# How to stop Automator / other task running in background

Tags: macbook-pro, automator, automation

I have a process on my MacBook that triggers when a new file is added to certain folders, like my desktop, it copies the file and places it in another directory that is backed up online.

The problem is I want to stop this copy behavior and really can not find where / what is running it. I think it was automator I created it with (it was a while ago), and I used to see a gear in the taskbar if that helps narrow it down. I no longer see the gear now.

Any suggestions would be very helpful thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bring up **Spotlight** (press command-space) and type in **folder action setup** and then press **Enter** when it comes up.

You can then disable/delete/etc the *folder action* on the target folder.

You can also, in **Finder**, right-click (control-click) on the target folder that has the *folder action* assigned to it as then select **Folder Action Setup...** in the **Services** section of the *context menu*.

[image: Folder Action Setup...]

Comment: This was exactly it thank you so much. I was with chatting with apple support and the response was "we don't really use automator" with a link that didn't help. Thank you